# Jquery set Date and display local format Chrome OK, FF Not

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, date, firefox

If I set a datestring like `2015-12-31` into a date input field with jquery, google chrome will show a german date style like `31.12.2015`, Firefox will show a date like `2015-12-31`.

```
  //will work in FF and chrome
  $('#dateinput').val('2015-12-31'); 
  //but FF displays 2015-12-31 whereas chrome displays 31.12.2015
```

If there any browser compatible solution to make all browsers showing the german (user local) date format?

If I change the string to:

```
  $('#dateinput').val('31.12.2015'); 
  //will not be accepted as a valid date from chrome.
```

Chrome will not work with this value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the correct datestring format:

```
2015-12-31T00:00:00Z
```

See if that works.